# Automapper mapping child properties in mapping profile class

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

Is the below code achievable?

If not, is there a similar approach to get child properties through methods in same class.

The reason to do it this was is to check for null and at the same time avoid creating multiple mapping profiles. Please guide me to the right direction on this one. Thanks

Its giving me this error:

Client projection contains reference to constant expression of 'Project.Web.Dto.Mapper.ProviderMappingProfile' through instance method 'GetLastUpdate'. This could potentially cause memory leak. Consider making the method static so that it does not capture constant in the instance.

```
    {
        public ProviderMappingProfile ()
        {
            CreateMap<Provider, ProviderDto>(MemberList.Destination)
                .ForMember(d => d.property1, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => GetLastUpdate(s)))
                .ForMember(d => d.property2, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => GetPropertChild2(s)));
        }

        private DateTime? GetLastUpdate(Provider provider)
        {
            var LastUpdate = provider.childDetails?.FirstOrDefault().LastUpdate;
            return LastUpdate;
        }

     
        private string GetPropertChild2(Provider provider)
        {
            if (provider.IsCombined)
            {
                return provider.CombinedNo;
            }
            return provider.Worker?.Work;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For `Expression` `MapFrom` overloads, the null check is built in. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html). And write some tests.

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your Get... methods into [custom resolvers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html):

```
public class LastUpdateResolver : IValueResolver<Provider, ProviderDto, DateTime?>
{
    public DateTime? Resolve(Provider source, ProviderDto destination, DateTime? member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.childDetails?.FirstOrDefault().LastUpdate;
    }
}
```

and use it on the profile declaration:

```
.ForMember(d => d.property1, opts => opts.MapFrom<LastUpdateResolver>())
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a generic way to accomplish this? i.e I would like to pass in multiple classes and dtos in there. LastUpdate property is present in multiple classes and having a single resolver to handle multiple class would do the trick!

Comment: In that case IValueConverter might be a better approach, for it is scoped to the property and agnostic about the containing class.